# Overpass API convert statement

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have read [Overpass API by example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example), but still I am unable to adapt `convert` statement examples to my need. What I would like to do is to get all marked routes in the area using Overpass Turbo, drop some tags and synthesize some new tags.

My query looks like this:

```
relation[route][route!="power"][route!="road"]({{bbox}});

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I would like to:

- add tag `color=green` when `osmc:symbol` contains green or when tag `kct_green` exists
- add tag `color=blue` when `osmc:symbol` contains blue or when tag `kct_blue` exists
- add tag `kind` as a value of any tags of `kct_green`, `kct_blue`, `kct_red`, `kct_green`
- remove some tags I no longer need to reduce output file size (like `kct_green`)

My initial naive attempt is:

```
relation[route][route!="power"][route!="road"]({{bbox}});

foreach (
  convert rel ::=::,
    ::id = id(),
    color=t["osmc:symbol"]
  ;

  out;
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

This kind of works, but lists relations without including their nodes. Moreover, I would like to perform a bit more processing on the color value:

- I want the `color` to be created only `osmc:symbol` is present
- I want to extract some information from `osmc:symbol` to `color`
- I have no idea how to create the combined value from those `kct_green`... tags.

I guess I need something more complex, however I have found almost no documentation or examples about `convert`. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Some of the things you mentioned are only available with 0.7.55 (geometry via `::geom()`) and are not yet documented (will follow soon). Otherwise, it's not quite clear what you mean by "osmc:symbol contains green". Is this meant as substring?

Comment: Yes, as substring. If this is not possible, how about other things? What is critical is nodes needs to be present in the output relation - without this it makes no sense to convert them.

Comment: Well, nodes are returned in a completely different format, as vertex: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/yO2 - not sure if this helps. Also, substring processing is not possible yet as part of an expression, it's simply not implemented.

Comment: The trouble with using the `::geom = geom()` is when I export such data as GeoJSON, they are empty. I was able to include relation ways and nodes by using `>` or its building blocks (`way(r)`, `node(r)`, `node(w)`), however only when not using `convert`. As soon as I use `convert`, `way(r)` stops working.

Comment: It sounds like you were better off downloading the relations, and do your own post processing locally.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation I have found at least a way to add and remove tags:

```
(
  relation[route][route="hiking"]({{bbox}});
  relation[route][route="foot"]({{bbox}});
  relation[route][route="mtb"]({{bbox}});
  relation[route][route="bicycle"]({{bbox}});
)->.routes;

foreach.routes (
  > -> .w;
  convert rel 
    ::id = id(),
    color=t["osmc:symbol"],
    !complete,
    !destinations,
    !type,
    ::=::
  ->.x;
  (.x;.w;);
  out;
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

If I will be able to achieve more, I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It shows this does not work as I expected. While it outputs the relation nodes, it does not output them as a part of the relation, but next to them :(